# How to loop through DOM and when a ID is clicked find corresponding class and toggle in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and coming from jQuery. I have the following code. I'm stuck on how to loop through my menu and when an element with id of `#vans-by-manufacturer` is clicked, then find an element with the same classname `.vans-by-manufacturer` and toggle a `.open` class on it?

```
const Nav = (props) => {
return (
<NavContainer className={props.open ? 'open' : ''}>
  <button className='close-menu' onClick={props.close}>close</button>
  <ul>
    <li><Link href='/'>Offers</Link></li>
    <li>
      <Link href='/'>Vans &rsaquo;</Link>
      <div className='menu-secondary-container'>
        <ul className='menu-secondary'>
          <li className='title'>
            <button type='button'>Vans</button>
          </li>
          <li className="home">
            <Link href="/van-leasing.html">Vans Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li className='has-tertiary'>
            <button type='button' 
              id='vans-by-manufacturer'>Vans By Manufacturer</button>
          </li>
          </ul>
          <ul className='menu-tertiary vans-by-manufacturer'>
            <li className='title'>
              <button type='button'>&lsaquo; Vans By Manufacturer</button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">Ford</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">Vauxhall</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><Link href='/'>Pickups</Link></li>
    <li><Link href='/'>Cars</Link></li>
  </ul>
</NavContainer>
    )} export default Nav
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi please refer my code and let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

Look into useRef react hook.
On your element with '.vans-by-manufacturer' add a ref.
Add an onClick listener on the #vans-by-manufacturer and when it is clicked use the "ref" on the '.vans-by-manufacturer' to toggle the 'open' class.